# Swift: sort array of [Any] by item type

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, types

I have an array that contains objects of different types. In my actual code these are custom types that conform to the same protocol, but the principle also applies to the following code:

```
let anyObjectArray: [Any] = [51, "g", "hello", 1, 30111]

var sortedArray: [Any] = []

for item in anyObjectArray where item is Int {
    sortedArray.append(item)
}
for item in anyObjectArray where item is String {
    sortedArray.append(item)
}
print(sortedArray)

// 51, 1, 30111, "g", "hello"
```

As you can see I want to sort the array by item type.

I am wondering if iterating several times over the array is an appropriate approach. Is there a possibility using .map to sort an array by item type, and if so, would that be more efficient?

The arrays in my actual code would contain a maximum of 4-5 elements, sometimes only one, on the other hand there would be more different types than just two, so the number of for in loops will be higher (possibly 4-5)

Comment: What would be the purpose of sorting by type? It is trivial to extract or loop thru one type, so why sort? How does sorting make the array better?

Comment: Even better, is this array really a good thing? Array of protocol is not really a useful type in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a horrible idea, and is almost certainly masking a major type-mistake, but not difficult to implement. You would sort by the types, just as you say. Since types aren't directly comparable, you can sort by their names.

```
anyObjectArray.sorted { "\(type(of: $0))" < "\(type(of: $1))" }
```

But this deeply feels like `Array` was the wrong type in the first place. It feels like you really want a dictionary here.

Comment: What exactly is the horrible idea - trying to sort the array, or the idea of having an array storing different types and accessing them in typely order in the first place?

string-interpolating the typename and sorting by that seems like an unwanted additional cast and limits me to do it alphabetically. I need a custom order, though.

Ok, I take it then iterating is effectively the simplest way to go

Comment: If you care about the underlying types, you didn't mean a protocol. You meant an enum (with associated data). And with an enum, sorting in whatever order you want would be straightforward. Fundamentally, if you find yourself "peeking" at the underlying type of something you've type-erased (via a protocol or via "Any"), you almost always have erased a type you didn't mean to erase. (There are some corner-case exceptions here, like `print` and in some cases `Codable`, but they're pretty rare.)

Answer (score 0):

This will not sort the array but group the elements by type in a dictionary

```
var map = [String: [Any]]()

anyObjectArray.forEach( {
    let key = "\([type(of: $0))"
    if map[key] == nil { map[key] = [] }
    map[key]?.append($0)
})
```

Or alternatively for Swift 4.2 (or later) as suggested by Rob Napier

```
let map = Dictionary(grouping: anyObjectArray, by: { "\(type(of: $0))" })
```

Comment: Swift 4.2 has made this approach dramatically simpler: `let map = Dictionary(grouping: anyObjectArray, by: { "\(type(of: $0))" })`

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks, looks like I am not up to speed with 4.2